# ASP.NET Image map control to open Ajax modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Can someone tell me a good example to open Ajax modal popup extender when clicking on image hotspot?

Currently I am receiving null exception(parameter name handler) when giving ID of imagemap as a targetcontrolid in extender.

Answer (score 1):

see http://forums.asp.net/t/1191143.aspx

```
<asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/MS.JPG">
         <asp:RectangleHotSpot Right="20" Top="20" NavigateUrl="javascript:showModal(0);"/>
</asp:ImageMap>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function showModal(index)
    {
        var modal = $find("behaviorIDOfModal");
        modal.show();
    }
</script>
```